# short circuit using OR

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
DECLARE @from_marked_price DECIMAL(18, 2), @to_marked_price DECIMAL(18, 2)
SELECT @from_marked_price = 3000
```

I have a filter like this

```
WHERE 
   @to_marked_price IS NOT NULL 
   OR @from_marked_price IS NULL 
   OR pd.marked_price >= @from_marked_price
```

However I don't get the expect result as that with

```
WHERE pd.marked_price >= 3000
```

am I doing something wrong here??

I can do it using dynamic sql but want to know if something is wrong here

Actually I got the answer
I had multiple queries like

```
WHERE
@to_marked_price IS NOT NULL OR @from_marked_price IS NULL OR pd.marked_price >= @from_marked_price
AND @from_marked_price IS NOT NULL OR @to_marked_price IS NULL OR pd.marked_price <= @to_marked_price
```

So what I did here wrong was I didn't place brackets properly, it should have been

```
WHERE
    (@to_marked_price IS NOT NULL OR @from_marked_price IS NULL OR pd.marked_price >= @from_marked_price)
    AND (@from_marked_price IS NOT NULL OR @to_marked_price IS NULL OR pd.marked_price <= @to_marked_price)
```

Sorry for troubling guys

Comment: Short circuiting doesn't work for DBMS'es, it's query optimizer that decides how to perform a query in a most efficient way.

Comment: @zerkms so whatever optimizer decides, I think the output should match in either case

Comment: What if you substitute the variable value with hardcoded `3000`. Will it produce the expected results?

Comment: @zerkms no it doesn't

Comment: so update the question and leave only what is relevant to the issue

Comment: What happens if you assign a value to `@to_marked_price`?

Comment: @zerkms I think having variable gives full meaning to the question I guess, like I want to use two variables to determine the possible query for ranges

Comment: @brykneval: your original query is broken and you're worrying about variables? Okay.

Comment: @zerkms so how do I address WHERE clause a NULL IS NOT NULL seems wierd or do you have any suggestion?

Comment: this sql fiddle works. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3c3df/5

Comment: Please show us the whole query and the db structure, it appears that the issue is not in the `WHERE` clause...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you've answered your question (putting the brackets in the correct place) but for completeness, the answer is

"You cannot short-circuit an expression unless you use the CASE statement."

that's why

`WHERE x<>0 and (100/x)>y` type of queries can still give div by zero and

```
WHERE 
CASE WHEN X=0 then NULL -- or whatever

ELSE (100/x) end
>y
```

will not.

Answer (score -1):

`Try this ...`

```
Select * from sometable
WHERE 
   @to_marked_price IS NOT NULL 
   OR ((@from_marked_price IS NULL) OR (pd.marked_price >= @from_marked_price))
```